# How to order list according to the value of variable? (php)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

First question to the people who know wordpress well: resource/system load wise is it better to query mysql directly and order result there? or use wordpress hooks WP_query fetch all posts and order them according to comments variable?

I've this code, it fetches everything. I'd like to order this list according to `comments_number( '0', '1', '%' );` (higher commented ones at the top) and limit total number displayed to top 4.

My code so far:

```
 <ul>
    <?php

    global $post;
    $all_events = tribe_get_events(
      array(
        'eventDisplay'=>'upcoming',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1
    )
    );

    foreach($all_events as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>

    <li>
          <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php
                      if ( has_post_thumbnail () ) {
                          echo get_the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100));
                      } else {
                          echo '<img width="100" height="100" alt="'
                               .get_the_title().'" title="'
                               .strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()).'" src="'
                               .get_bloginfo('template_url')
                               .'/thumbs/event-recent-thumb-na.png">';
                      }
                    ?>
          </a>

          <h3><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          <span><?php echo tribe_get_start_date( $p->ID, true, 'M j, D.' ) . " - "
                         . tribe_get_end_date( $p->ID, true, 'D.' ); ?></span>
          <p><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?></p>
          <span class="eventinterested"><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?>
          <?php _e('interested so far','holidayge'); ?></span>
    </li>

    <?php } //endforeach ?>

          <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

 </ul>
```

Is there a way to modify `foreach` and order list there? I'm not php programmer, but it seems logical... I'm reading about [Sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) seems like correct solution?

Comment: @vzwick I'm reading php:sort right now and gonna try that.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a whole lot faster at queries than PHP is, so you should try not to ask for more posts than you want. Loading all posts into PHP does not scale very well.

I'm guessing that tribe_get_events() uses get_posts(). If that's correct, this should do the trick:

```
$all_events = tribe_get_events(
    array(
        'eventDisplay'   => 'upcoming',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
        'order'          => 'DESC'
    )
);
```

More info can be found in [the documentation on get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).